# How to select fields to be displayed in generic ListView class in Django?

Tags: python, django, listview

I'm using Django (v1.7) and I'm looking for a "Django style" way to select the fields to be displayed in a generic.ListView.

Let me provide an example:

In models.py:

```
class Stuff(generic.models):
    field1 = model.CharField()
    field2 = model.CharField()
    field3 = model.CharField()
```

In views.py:

```
class StuffList(generic.ListView)
    model = Stuff
```

In template/stuff_index.html

```
{% for stuff in object_list %}
    Field1: {{ stuff.field1 }}
    Field3: {{ stuff.field3 }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

Is there a way to indicate in views.py the fields to be displayed? So that views.py and template/stuff_index.html would look like:

views.py:

```
class StuffList(generic.ListView)
    model = Stuff
    fields = ['field1','field3']     # Or something similar
```

In template/stuff_index.html

```
{% for stuff in object_list %}
    {% for field in stuff %}
        {{ field.name }}: {{ stuff.field }}     <!-- Or something similar -->
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is this way of coding somehow handled by Django framework ? I succedded to have something similar by redefining the returned value of *get_queryset()* method in StuffList class, but it's not a "smart" solution.

Comment: If you're looking for the normal way to do this it's the first way you've specified - just don't reference the parts of the object you don't want to show in your template. Is there a reason why you'd rather do this in your view?

Comment: Actually, I want to have a generic template and use it to render several lists of different objects. And that way looks to me more DRY-like: it's easy for the developer to add or remove a field to be displayed.
But you seem to be right, the only way I found over examples and the internet consist of coding the elements to display directly in the template.

Comment: It's best not to use templates that way because you'll end up with too much logic in the template as you try to handle special cases each list of objects introduces. Instead, make your templates DRY using template inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I think get_context_data is what you might be looking for.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

Comment: Thank you @user4107395. The examples provide for this functions are not well explaining the usage I'm looking for. Could you extend your answer with a link to HOWTO or to a tutorial or with an example of use ?
Thank you again.

Comment: Hum, I think I know what you are trying to do.  I did another quick search and ran into the following which might be a little closer. http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2014/05/19/context.html

Comment: Hey yes, it's getting closer ! I've never tried to use a TemplateView that way. The solution might be to define a variable containing the fields to be displayed in the view class, and to use a *{% for foo in fooList %}* in the template which iterate over the fields. I'll give it a try. Thank you!